# How should I persist my event stream to cold storage?

Tags: hadoop, bigdata, apache-kafka, amazon-kinesis, azure-eventhub

I have a stream of events (we could alternatively call them "messages" or even just "data") coming from an *event broker* with time-based retension. The event broker could be [Kafka](http://kafka.apache.org/) or [Amazon Kinesis](http://aws.amazon.com/kinesis/) or [Microsoft Event Hubs](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/event-hubs/), though let's say that it's Kafka.

My goal is take this event stream and put it into *cold storage*; that is, to store the data for future analysis via Hadoop/Spark. This means that I'd like to take this "chatty" stream of events and convert it to "chunky" files in HDFS. In a cloud environment, I'd likely use S3 or Azure Storage instead of HDFS.

I'd also like my solution to be cost effective; for example, using serialization formats such as Avro/ORC in order to reduce my disk space cost. I'm also like an at-least-once guarentee that a given event is persited to cold storage (bonus points for once-and-only-once).

My core questions are:

- **How are people solving this problem?**
- **Are there components out there already handle this scenario?**
- **Do I need to develop a solution myself?**
- **In the least, are they any recommended patterns?**

Answer (score 3):

Well, we are using kafka with [camus](https://github.com/linkedin/camus) to fetch data from kafka into HDFS. Camus supports avro serialization. You can find more about camus and avro [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/camus_etl/4f-Ru7Rhn8w).

Answer (score 1):

Another option is using Flume with a Kafka source (or Kafka channel) and HDFS sink. HDFS sink can be configured to roll at specific sizes or times.